# Can a single college course section be taught by two professors?

Tags: course-design

For example, having half of the lessons taught by one professor, and the other half of the lessons taught by another professor.

If this isn't possible, why isn't it possible?  Can you provide any links to further information on how it's done (e.g. dividing the compensation)?

Comment: It's certainly possible; I've attended a lot of such courses. The professors teach different topics based on their specialty.

Comment: It's often called "team teaching" or "co-teaching".  Arrangements could vary, but the simplest thing would be to split the compensation 50/50.

Comment: It is pretty common. Regulations, details can be different country by country, university by university.

Comment: Yes. And without further context, that's all can be said. Why are are asking? Were you requested to do so? Are you supposed to organize it for someone? Supervise it?

Answer (score 3):

For several years I taught a doctoral level course with a colleague. We were both always present for every class. Each of us took a different "perspective" with the material. One of us would take the lead at any given moment and the other would comment as he felt inclined. Students could ask either of us questions at any time.

The course was very broad, but, generally speaking, centered on *Agile Software Development*, both its technical and managerial aspects. It was a bit broader than that implies, actually.

We were both salaried, as is typical in US, and each of us got "full credit" for a course taught. The course was considered important enough by the university that the pay issue was basically ignored.

Not every university would be willing to ignore pay issues, of course, and, I suspect, no university would make a general practice of it for many courses. Few would, anyway.

Comment: "no university would make a general practice of it." I know one where every student is required to take a "senior seminar" which is taught by two faculty.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, actually, I meant for every course. Clarified now.

Comment: I can think of at least one world-famous university in which certain departments teach virtually *all* their classes this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, obviously. As for the details, it varies hugely between different countries and universities so you won't get a precise answer.

Answer (score -1):

I shared a course with two other professors, we each taught our own cohort of students - biggest issue is making sure you all cover the same material per week. Students ask questions that can easily cause "drift" away from the main topic - usually interesting, but the main material still needs covering as that is what is in the exam.

I have shared other courses where I covered one set of topics and the other covered a different set of topics - works fine but you have to stick to what was agreed and communicate.

Comment: Thank you for responding! When you say "shared a course", you mean it was a single course section?

Comment: It was a module, we shared it, all teaching the same material.

Comment: +1 I have also co-taught courses where I covered a subset of the material (lectures, homework, exam questions, etc.) and the other instructor covered the rest.  I have also co-taught courses where the other instructor gave all the lectures and I wrote all the homeworks and exams and handled all the other administrivia.  In both cases, all instructors were paid their full salary.  There are many many models.